# Application web: message sending

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, instant-messaging

I am developing a web application where several clients can send messages to each other, it would be like instant messaging without strong real-time constraint.

To illustrate the situation, let's imagine a classroom where students are on a web page and can send messages to their teacher who is on another web page displaying all the messages.
The teacher can answer questions and therefore the pages of the students who have received answers must update with the respective answer.

The first research of solution are unsuccessful because it turns around form and installation of specific library.

What is the easiest solution to implement?
For information, I am developing with javascript, php and mysql; I have no possibility to modify the server part nor to install libraries.

Thank you.
LG

Comment: The easiest and by far the best solution for this kind of 2-way real-time communication is to use websockets, but since that would likely require you to configure a long-running PHP background process in order to work, it might not be feasible for your scenario. Possible options for you: 1) move to a server where you have more control over the environment, 2) try to integrate your app with a 3rd-party socket service (e.g. Azure SignalR or similar), 3) stop using PHP because it sucks at websockets anyway, 4) fall back to the poor-man's 2000s solution of using AJAX polling.

Comment: In first intention I actually thought about solution 4: ajax request every 10s to see if a response in the database is for my page. With the preliminary obtaining of a "client id" provided by the server.

Comment: Yeah you can certainly do that. It's just very inefficient - a) it's quite a long way from "real-time", and b) it can easily overload your server when you have a lot of users, due to the overhead of endless HTTP requests. That's why people use websockets instead. My advice would be - use the right tool for the job. If your environment doesn't support the tool, get a new environment. (Also as an aside, PHP is not very good at websockets - even the leading solutions aren't great. I'd be building an app like this with something more async-friendly like nodeJS or ASP.NET Core (just my opinion))